# OnChange of a Component binding in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a component in angular js which shows some data 
But on change of my customer binding i want to call some service in component controller which is not reflecting,Here is the below code

In my Test1.html

```
<tab-customer title="Test Comp" customerCode="vm.customerCode"  functioname="fnTest"></tab-customer>
```

`vm.CustomerCode` is changing on basis of dropdown so its changing

`app.comp.TestComp` is already defined

```
angular
        .module('app.comp.TestComp')
        .component('tabCustomer', {
            templateUrl: 'Component.html',
            controller: tabCompCustomer,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
                title: '@',
                functioname: '@',
                customerCode: '<'
            }
        });
function tabCompCustomer(tableCustomerService, $rootScope,$scope, $filter) {
        var vm = this;
         $scope.$watch('vm.customerCode', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('got1')
            console.log(newValue) // This is also not working
        });

        $onChanges = function (changes) {
            console.log('got')
            console.log(changes) // This is also not working
        };
};
```

On Change of a Customer Code i need to fire my component again but i am not getting any fire event can anyone help

If the question is still unclear comment i will detailed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be changing your attribute binding from `customerCode` to `customer-code`, So that will pass `vm.customerCode` to component. And remove `$watch` function from component controller, as `$onChanges` function will get fire automatically on each `bindings` change.

```
customerCode="vm.customerCode"
```

should be

```
customer-code="vm.customerCode"
```

> **Note:** make `$onChanges =` to `this.$onChanges =`

Comment: Thanx i didnt checked that,thanku but not $onChanges is still not working ,am i doing any mistake please help